# building encryption SHA 1 from Parameter for android to json parse

Tags: android, json, encryption, key, sha1

I have problem with build Encryption from String to SHA 1 encrypt maybe in here can help me

This my Parameter

```
             String AgentID = "7001";
             String AgentPIN = "68820025";
             String ScreetKey = "63e3cd0a";
             String AgentTrxID = "201802090013";
             String AgentStoreID = "01010101";
             String pdam = pdam1;
             String CustomerID = 
             edit_nomorpelangganpdam.getText().toString().trim();
             String DateTimeRequest = (String) 
             DateFormat.format("yyyyMMddHHmmss", new Date());
```

And this my code for SHA 1

```
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : data) {
        int halfbyte = (b >>> 4) & 0x0;
        int two_halfs = 0;
        do {
            buf.append((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9) ? (char) ('0' + halfbyte) : (char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
            halfbyte = b & 0x0F;
        } while (two_halfs++ < 1);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}

public static String SHA1(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, text.length());
    byte[] sha1hash = md.digest();
    return convertToHex(sha1hash);
}
```

I want to make like this Encryption

93d97a890c312a7f33ca2c393ec070a7e1b42cdc

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
    // Call this method where you wont        
    encryptString("Your String value")

    private static String encryptString(String value)
    {
        String sha1 = "";
        try
        {
            MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            crypt.reset();
            crypt.update(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            sha1 = byteToHexadecimal(crypt.digest());
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sha1;
    }

    private static String byteToHexadecimal(final byte[] hash)
    {
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (byte b : hash)
        {
            formatter.format("%02x", b);
        }
        String result = formatter.toString();
        formatter.close();
        return result;
    }
```